# What am I doing wrong with my /give command?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am working on an adventure mode map on the Nintendo Switch Bedrock Edition, and so I am trying to give myself a diamond pickaxe which can only break mob spawners and is unbreakable. I have currently:

`/give @s diamond_pickaxe 1 0 {CanDestroy:["minecraft:mob_spawner"],Unbreakable:1}`

and whenever I enter the command I get:

> Line 1, Column 2 missing '}' or object member name.

I have gone off of a couple tutorials and this is the closest I can get to having it work.

Can anyone please tell me where the error is?

Comment: My current theory is that this is a difference between Java Edition and Bedrock Edition NBT format. I'll have to look at this a little deeper at home, and maybe do some testing on my Windows 10 install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, thank you @SpiceWeasel for indirectly helping me figure out the issue. There is no NBT data with the give command on bedrock edition.

Comment: Ah, Bedrock Edition. The fine print I always miss :P

Answer (score 2):

The command you're using is pre-1.13 synax. The command for 1.13 is:

```
/give @s diamond_pickaxe{CanDestroy:["list of blocks you want the pick to destroy here"],Unbreakable:1b} 1
```

You can view all 1.13 command changes here: https://minecraft.wiki/w/1.13#Command_format_2

Comment: While this is actually not very helpful for my situation it did lead me to figure it out.